# Contour integral: $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^5-1}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

The integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^5-1}\mathrm dx
$$

I have tried taking the typical half circle contour and finding the enclosed residues:
$$
\text{Res}(f,1)=\frac{1}{5}\\
\text{Res}(f,e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}})=\frac{e^{\frac{8\pi i}{15}}}{5}\\
\text{Res}(f,e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}})=\frac{e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{15}}}{5}
$$
By Jordan's lemma, the arc contributes nothing. However, I have a problem with the non integrable singularity at 1 on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Can I deviate to avoid it while also keeping track of the contribution from the positive real axis? There doesn't seem to be great symmetry at $1$ thanks to the numerator. Is my contour not a good choice?

edit: Also tried changing variables to evaluate on the positive real axis, but this again introduces the bad singularity.

Comment: What's your $x^{1/3}$-definition ?. Without that we don't have any clue about the whole integration meaning.

Comment: @FelixMarin I don't know, it is from a qualification exam I was using to practice. Presumably, if you do valid things given a certain branch cut it is taken to be correct

Comment: I guess the Jack answer assumption $\left(x^{1/3} = \mathrm{sgn}\left(x\right)\left\vert x\right\vert^{1/3}\right)$ is a reasonable def... when we don't have enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $x^{1/3}$ is defined as $-(-x)^{1/3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^-$, the change of variable $x=-z^3$ bring the given integral in the form
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3z^3}{z^{15}+1}\,dz $$
and by setting $\frac{1}{1+z^{15}}=u$ the previous integral can be computed through Euler's [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). By exploiting the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function, $\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$, such integral simplifies to
$$ \frac{\pi}{5\sin\frac{4\pi}{15}}=\frac{\pi}{5\cos\frac{7\pi}{30}}=\frac{4\pi}{5\sqrt{7-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6 \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)}}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jack! Out of curiosity, do you see a good way to evaluate this without appealing to "special" functions?

Comment: @qbert: contour integration works, you just have to "dodge" the singularity at $z=1$ by introducing a suitable deformation of the contour, but the approach above is way more efficient in my opinion.